# Is there any way to get the id of "Android WebView" app?

Tags: php, android, web, server

I use this php code to check if the user open my website from a Webview or from a browser and i want to get the id of "Android App WebView" apk which is on the playstore
but i don't find it and i also want the id of "Google Chrome" apk.
Id example: "com.facebook.orca".

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "com.facebook.orca")
echo 'var isWebView=true;';
else
echo 'var isWebView=false;';
```

Comment: Simply set up a custom header which only your app would send during a request. If the header is missing, block the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that a `package name` is in url of Google Play, an `id` param...

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en

you can probably list all package names from device in some "advanced" settings or just find an app for that in Play Store

Comment: thanks for your help but do you know why when i use the id it doesnot work ?

Comment: not every app/site will send refer variable, there is no reliable way to identify in which app your site was opened, it may not send this info or change it (like useragent)